# How do I escape three backticks surrounded by a codeblock in Markdown?

Tags: markdown, hexo

First, I'd like to say that I've read some recommended questions that may seem to answer my question, but they're all about escape **single** backtick in markdown. I've tried but none of them seem to work.

Here's what I've tried.

1. Double backtick - single space - three backticks.

   [image: To avoid any problems, I use image to discribe.]

   and it seems to be good in my markdown editor except missing the breakline. But bad luck, it seems terrible on Hexo blog.

   Then I test in Github for luck. And, difference shows:

   [image: Shown in github.]
2. Use backslash.

Unfortunately, it shows directly instead of escape the backtick.

Now, my question is, it works well here in Stack Overflow, but not in my blog. What else I should try except using html tag, or is it the only way I should go? Is it the issue with my usage or my blog theme?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In addition to nesting a fenced block inside an indented block (as demonstrated in another answer), you can also nest one fenced block inside another fenced block by using a different number of backticks (as you have tried). However, you must keep each set of deliminators on a separate line. And most implementations require three or more backticks (your use of 2 is another failure point). For example, notice that in the following example the outer block uses four backticks whereas the inner block uses three backticks:

`````
````
```
UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
```
````
`````

In many implementations that will render as:

````
```
UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
```
````

You may find this is not supported properly with some implementations however.

As an alternative, if the implementation you are using also supports tildes (`~`) as fenced code block deliminators, you can use those instead:

````
~~~
```
UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
```
~~~
````

Again, never use less that three deliminator characters in a group and always include each group on a separate line by itself.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to represent code blocks in most Markdown implementations:

- indent the whole block by four characters or one tab, [as in the original implementation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode), and
- use fenced code blocks, [as in GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#fenced-code-blocks).

You can *combine* these techniques, causing the triple backticks from your fenced block to be treated part of the indented code block, e.g.

````
    ```
    UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    ```
````

This snippet renders like this on Stack Overflow:

````
```
UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
```
````

Comment: This is a great one because it turns out that pressing the tab key on a selection in a github comment window indents the selection, so it is very easy to do and clean.